# Month and year only in dropdown with jQuery not working on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker to have month and year only as dropdown to select.

When i am using below CSS to disable the days of the datepicker, it is disabling the other datepickers in my JSP.

1.How can i make this css inline to one desired datepicker alone.

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
display: none;
}
```

2.once after disabling i am using onselect to select the month and year which is not working but it works if i select day in calendar with full calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#txtDate').datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     dateFormat: 'M yy',
     yearRange: "-2:+0",
     defaultDate: '-1m',

     onSelect: function() {
        var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").text();
        var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();


        callmymethod();
        }
        });
         });
```

pls help me with these 2 queries. Thank you

Comment: I guess your first requirement is unachievable until you use that class in the page where textbox is &  for your second query see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bopperben/DBpJe/

Comment: Select Month:<input type='text' id='txtDate' /> this is how my textbox is, pls let me know what class to add here

Answer (score 1):

i have got the solution for this which exactly served my purpose

[jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/jM9Wm/99/)

```
<input type="text" data-calendar="false" />
<input type="text" data-calendar="false" />
<input type="text" data-calendar="true" />
```

jQuery

```
$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(el, dp) {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').toggleClass('hide-calendar',   $(el).is('[data-calendar="false"]'));
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.hide-calendar .ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```